# Include stylesheets using browserify-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) to include [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) in my Rails project. My `application.coffee` contains the following:

```
require('angular-ui-grid')
```

This works in the sense that includes `node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js`, but it doesn't handle any of the stylesheets.

How can I get Angular UI Grid's stylesheets into my application as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript includes and CSS includes are handled separately.

Your `require('angular-ui-grid')` call above handles the JS side of things since it's in the `application.coffee` manifest file.

To include the stylesheets, you'll need an additional `require` in the `application.scss` (or whichever file is your main CSS manifest).

`browserify-rails` does not include the `node_modules` directory in its asset load paths by default, so you have to add it inside the `assets.rb` file like this

```
# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "node_modules"
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. This project has `@import` statements in `application.css.scss` rather than `require`s and my `*= require angular-ui-grid` doesn't get parsed, it just stays commented when I view the actual CSS file. So I gotta figure that out. Any suggestions are of course welcome.

Comment: Try using `@import <name of CSS file>` inside your CSS.

Comment: I ended up just moving `application.css.scss` to `main.css.scss` which allowed me to use `*= require ...` in `application.css.scss`. Now my challenge is that it says `couldn't find file 'angular-ui-grid' with type 'text/css'`. So apparently I don't have the filename/path quite right yet.

Comment: Cool, we're almost there. What you need to tell it is the location of the CSS file relative to the `node_modules` directory. This directory should exist in your project so you can just look in there and find the file (and path) that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. I actually did try that. The full path to the CSS file is `node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css`, so I tried `*= require angular-ui-grid/ui-grid`, but I still get the `couldn't find file...` error.

Comment: Let's confirm that `node_modules` is indeed in the asset paths. Can you look at the value of `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` (maybe do this in the Rails console)

Comment: Ah, good idea. It looks like `node_modules` is in fact *not* in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`. I'll google how to add it but I have a feeling you might just tell me. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114264/discussion-between-carlos-ramirez-iii-and-jason-swett).